# Postfix 4.3.0 error FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, postfix

!02.03.2016, 01:42:36: SEND  - Message has not been sent. Server reply - 4.3.0 : Temporary lookup failure

```
myhostname = smtp.zone03.com.ua
mydomain = zone03.com.ua
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.18.0.0/16, 192.168.56.0/24
alias_database = hash:/usr/local/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = $alias_database
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
```

DNS

```
$TTL 3600
@       IN      SOA     zone03.com.ua. root.zone03.com.ua. (
                                2013030400      ; Serial
                                3600            ; Refresh
                                900             ; Retry
                                3600000         ; Expire
                                3600 )          ; Minimum
@               IN      NS      ns1.zone03.com.ua.
@               IN      NS      ns2.zone03.com.ua.
@               MX      10      smtp.zone03.com.ua.
@               IN      A       10.18.51.1
ns1             IN      A       10.18.51.1
ns2             IN      A       10.18.51.31
smtp            IN      A       10.18.51.1
mercury         IN      A       10.18.3.10
venus           IN      A       10.18.3.20
earth           IN      A       10.18.3.30
mars            IN      A       10.18.3.40
fralewan        IN      A       10.18.3.50
ws1             IN      CNAME   mercury
ws2             IN      CNAME   venus
ws3             IN      CNAME   earth
ws4             IN      CNAME   mars
ws5             IN      CNAME   fralewan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ee /usr/local/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
myhostname = smtp.zone03.com.ua
mydomain = zone03.com.ua
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 10.18.0.0/16, 192.168.56.0/24
alias_database = hash:/usr/local/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_maps = $alias_database
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/usr/local/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
```

sudo

```
postmap /usr/local/etc/postfix/virtual
postmap /usr/local/etc/postfix/aliases
```